Failed to install Culative Updates
I was trying to install the SharePoint Language CU on an Air-Gapped system:

wssloc2019-kb5002597-fullfile-x64-glb.exe

wssloc2019-kb5002597-fullfile-x64-glb.exe
It fails with the following message:

The installation of this package failed

As an Administrator, I've run the config wizard and restart the servers in my Farm; it always fails
I've checked the log file the installer outputs, I didn't find any hints as to what the issue might be.
Any ideas about how I can install this update?  Again, my Farm has no internet access.

Don't forget about the compatibility of the updates you install. You also need to check what updates are missing to install your package wssloc2019-kb5002597-fullfile-x64-glb.exe.
Most likely you already have packages installed, but they are not deployed, because of this other update packages are not installed, try to update all installed on the farm first using the PowerShell command:
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

Necessarily Upgrade Database:
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content


Can you suggest something else?  Unfortunately, this command did not work. All Servers were successfully configured and Central Admin claims that for all the servers "No Action Required".  However, the CU still refuses to install.

Does it currently work SharePoint without a language pack?

SharePoint is currently working.  Since I can't install the CU at all, SharePoint claims that there are no actions to take.
